# Verify ECDSA Key Fingerprint of Azure Linux VM

Tags: azure, ssh-keys

I'm starting to play with bash on Windows (Insider Preview build 14316) and have created a Linux VM in Azure. When I ssh into it, I'm presented with "The authenticity of host '##.##.##.##' can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx."

How do I verify that the fingerprint belongs to my new VM?

**Edit:** To clarify, [as best as I can find](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-portal-create/) one can only connect to an Azure Linux VM via SSH. I have scoured the [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com/) for the fingerprint to no avail. I think I need to either connect to the VM other than through SSH (at which point I can use `ssh-keygen`) or get the fingerprint through the portal, but I can't figure out how to do either; I'm open to other approaches I've overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

When you're logged in locally to the Linux VM (i.e. not via SSH), you can [display](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1) the fingerprint of the [SSH host key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys):

```
$ ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub -l
256 MD5:68:b3:29:da:98:93:e3:40:99:c7:d8:ad:5c:b9:c9:40 no comment (ECDSA)
```

This fingerprint should match the characters you were presented when you tried to login via SSH:

```
$ ssh VM
The authenticity of host 'VM (192.168.0.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 68:b3:29:da:98:93:e3:40:99:c7:d8:ad:5c:b9:c9:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Note: newer `ssh-keygen` versions may need the "`-E md5`" switch to print out the MD5 fingerprint.

Comment: So, it's a chicken-and-egg problem then: if Azure VM gives you no other way to login and doesn't provide you the SSH host key fingerprint via any other means (e.g. it could show it to you in the control panel), then there's no way to verify the key **before** logging in. If the VM has just been installed, chances are that the VM has not been compromised yet and you could just login (and accept the fingerprint) and then run the ```ssh-keygen``` command from above to check if the fingerprint you just accepted matches the host key fingerprint. _(Hm? Where did the comment go I just replied to?)_

Comment: Sorry, I fat-fingered the 'Delete' link while browsing on my phone; I've recreated its gist & more as an edit to the question itself (where others are likelier to read it).

Comment: You should not be using `sudo` for that command. No special privileges are required to read the public key. And when typing it with `sudo` you are only a small typo away from overwriting the key.

Comment: @kasperd: you're right of course, I don't know why I used sudo here; it's removed now.

Comment: On first boot, the keys are generated and output to the boot diagnostics, which can be views in the portal. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39464677/347061).